About $V(I)=V( \hspace{0.1cm}\langle I\rangle)\hspace{0.1cm})$ and closedness of $V(I)$.
I am self studying commutative algebra and have two questions about the topic about varieties of an ideal commutative ring $R$, $$V(I)=\{P\in \operatorname{Spec}(R): I\subseteq P \}$$
The one of the property of variety is that we don't need necessarily to have an ideal $I$, we can have a subset $I\subseteq R$ and one can define variety by just taking the ideal generated by $(I)$. Here's my problem, I couldn't figure out that why $V(I)=V( \hspace{0.1cm}\langle I\rangle)\hspace{0.1cm})$.
One direction is straightforward because $I \subseteq \langle I \rangle$ then $V( \hspace{0.1cm}\langle I\rangle)\hspace{0.1cm}) \subseteq V(I)$. For the other direction, everyone says that since $\langle I \rangle$ is the smallest ideal containing $I$ or it is the intersection all of the ideals of $R$ containing $I$ then it immediately implies that $V(I) \subseteq V( \hspace{0.1cm}\langle I\rangle)\hspace{0.1cm})$. I couldn't see the reasoning.
My second question is the following: I know that varieties have a couple of properties but everyone directly says that $V(I)$ satisfies axioms to be closed set in the topological space? Okay, it is clear that $\emptyset=V(R)$ and $V(0)=R$, these two lies in $V(I)$.

Hint for the first question: the ideal generated by a subset $S\subset R$ consists of elements of the form $\sum r_i a_i$ for $a_i\in S, r_i\in R$.

Given a subset $S\subseteq R$, the ideal generated by $S$ is the smallest in the following sense: if $I$ is an ideal that contains $S$ then it also contains $\langle S\rangle$. So it really is straightforward: if $P\in V(I)$ then $I\subseteq P$, and then $\langle I\rangle\subseteq P$, i.e $P\in V(\langle I\rangle)$.
As for these sets being the closed set of a topology, we need to show that arbitrary intersections and finite unions of varieties is again a variety. And indeed, it can be checked that:
$\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}V(I_i)=V(\sum\limits_{i\in I}I_i)$
$V(I)\cup V(J)=V(I\cap J)$
Try to prove this. The first property is really straightforward, the second is a bit more interesting. You need to show that if a prime ideal contains $I\cap J$ then it must contain either $I$ or $J$.

Dear Mark, thank you for your response, it helps me to break my ices. One more thing, why do we need to show that arbitrary intersections and finite unions of varieties is again a variety?

@FuatRay If I understood correctly, your second question was about showing that there is a topology on $\text{Spec}(R)$ such that the varieties are its closed sets. You mentioned that the empty set and the whole space are varieties. So it is left to prove that varieties are closed under finite unions and arbitrary intersections.

Dear @Mark, allow me to explain myself step by step. I have a set $X=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ with $\tau={V(I): I\subseteq R }$. Indeed, $\tau$ satisfies being conditions of topology; i) $\emptyset$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(R) \in V(I)$. Moreover, finite union of $V(I)$ is again variety and finite intersection of varieties is variety. I couldn't still see the reason that why $V(I)$ are closed set?

@FuatRay No, the $\tau$ you defined is not a topology. In order to be a topology, $\tau$ has to be closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections. The varieties are the exact opposite: they are closed under finite unions and arbitrary intersections. But because they have these properties, their complements do satisfy the axioms of a topology. So the topology I was talking about is $\tau={X\setminus V(I): I\subseteq R}$. The elements of the topology are the complements, and so the sets $V(I)$ are the closed sets.

Excellent explanation! Many thanks.
